# Let user resize control (textbox, specifically) in Canvas UWP

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, textbox, user-controls

I have a canvas with a button that the user can press to add a new textbox to the canvas. How can I make it so the user can resize the text box by clicking and dragging on any of the corners of the textbox. Because the textbox is created in the C# code (not XAML), I would prefer code in C# not XAML.

Thanks

EDIT: My question is different than the one referenced because it is in UWP not WPF. These have very different controls. I would appreciate if you could translate the UWP information into UWP C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing TextBox At Runtime in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834452/resizing-textbox-at-runtime-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thumb control instead of a textbox. The thumb control provides the functionality for you to write code to customize the drag and drop behavior. A simple code would be:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="test">
        <Thumb Width="100" Height="100">
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="12345"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>
    </Canvas>
```

A more complex sample could be found from this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545896/universal-windows-uwp-range-slider) from Jay's answer. But please notice you need to customize the logic yourself in order to make it resize like what you need. The reference is just a direction.